# Multipass ubuntu dns not work when accessed from windows host, but work fine in ubuntu vm?

Tags: networking, dns, virtualization

1. Standard multipass installation (default virtual nat)
2. Run pihole from docker with port 53 shared from docker to ubuntu-vm
3. Dns can be accessed from ubuntu-vm with nameserver 127.0.0.1 in /etc/resolv.conf
4. In windows Ping and pihole web can be accessed by typing ubuntu-vm ip address in windows browser.
5. But when setting dns in windows to use ubuntu-vm ip address, ping and nslookup failed for external domain like google.com and so on
   *Edit ubuntu version is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (codename jammy)

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To make it easier to diagnose, and for those members who may run into this same issue in the future, can you please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running? Thanks